# Parse html templates into client side JS. Angular + Browserify + Babel + ES2015 + Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have issue with Browserify Angular config file, where i `require()` HTML templates. I tried to make `stringify`, or `browserify-ng-html2js`
 in `transform()` , but in this case I have multiple transform calls in gulp file, and I can't make it well without errors. Chaining giver error also.

APP.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import appModule from './config/config'

angular.bootstrap( document, [ appModule.name ] );
```

Config.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

const app = angular.module( 'app', [ uiRouter ] );

app.config(( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) => {
  $urlRouterProvider.other( '/' );

  $stateProvider
    .state( 'todos', {
      url: '/',
      template: require( '../views/todos.html' )
    } )
    .state( 'about', {
      url: '/about',
      template: require( '../views/about.html' )
    } );

  $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
});

export default app;
```

and Gulp Browserify Task:

```
/** Browserify TASK **/
gulp.task( 'browserify', function () {

  let bundler = browserify({
    entries: [ config.sourceDir + 'app.js' ],
    debug: true
  });

util.log( '-> Compile JS...' );

  //Grab files
  return bundler
  .transform( 'babelify', { presets: [ "es2015", "react" ] } )
  .bundle()
  .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      this.emit('end');
    })
  .pipe( source( 'bundle.js' ) )
  .pipe( buffer() )
  .pipe( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }) )
    .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )
  //Dest
  .pipe( gulp.dest( config.buildDir ) )
} );
```

Now when I try to Browserify APP i get error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'todos/todos.html'
```

Any hints and help will be appreciated:) Thanks and regards!

PS. I tried with:

```
  .transform( stringify, {
    appliesTo: { includeExtensions: [ 'html', 'htm', 'jsp' ] },
    minify: true
  } )
```

But problem is still.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solve that:
There is two options to solve this problem:

First is to require() HTML files via browserify, to not use them like JS, we need to install one of transforms -> npm i -D html2js-browserify and attach it to gulpfile:

```
.transform( 'html2js-browserify' )
```

second option is to copy all views into public/static dir where we set in express to serve all static files, and use `templateUrl: <path-to-template-inside-public-dir>` I hope it will help anyone. Regards!